# multi slide for customers

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

I am developing a website magento version 1.9 for a client.
it would like to have a different banner per group customers.
for example;
Group 1 customers to slide 1
Group customers 2 to slide 2 etc.

the precision slide is a static block
this is the web site concerned

http://magento.site-en-prod.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of Magento Enterprise. You can have banners that load and change content based on customer segments.

Otherwise you're stuck with custom developing a widget in Magento CE or implementing a 3rd party tool.